# Class Vector with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, computational-geometry

Here is a class vector in python 3, for n-dimmensional vectors. Please suggest ways to improve the code as well as fix bugs and errors.

***The only rule is not using: numpy, sympy, scipy and so on. Only math, cmath, Rational, Decimal, ... Python 3 default packages.***.

This code is only for learning to make classes with python 3. I want comments to improve my python learning.  For example, a way to improve the `__init()__` constructor, and so on.

```
# /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Created on Wed May  7 21:21:21 2014

@author: tobal
'''

from math import sqrt, acos, degrees, radians, cos, sin, fsum, hypot, atan2


class Vector(tuple):

    '''"Class to calculate the usual operations with vectors in bi and
    tridimensional coordinates. Too with n-dimmensinal.'''
    # __slots__=('V') #It's not possible because V is a variable list of param.
    def __new__(cls, *V):
        '''The new method, we initialize the coordinates of a vector.
        You can initialize a vector for example: V = Vector() or
        V = Vector(a,b) or V = Vector(v1, v2, ..., vn)'''
        if not V:
            V = (0, 0)
        elif len(V) == 1:
            raise ValueError('A vector must have at least 2 coordinates.')
        return tuple.__new__(cls, V)

    def __add__(self, V):
        '''The operator sum overloaded. You can add vectors writing V + W,
        where V and W are two vectors.'''
        if len(self) != len(V):
            raise IndexError('Vectors must have same dimmensions.')
        else:
            added = tuple(a + b for a, b in zip(self, V))
            return Vector(*added)

    __radd__ = __add__

    def __sub__(self, V):
        '''The operator subtraction overloaded. You can subtract vectors writing
        V - W, where V and W are two vectors.'''
        if len(self) != len(V):
            raise IndexError('Vectors must have same dimmensions.')
        else:
            subtracted = tuple(a - b for a, b in zip(self, V))
            return Vector(*subtracted)

    def __rsub__(self, V):
        '''The operator subtraction overloaded. You can subtract vectors writing
        W - V, where V and W are two vectors.'''
        if len(self) != len(V):
            raise IndexError('Vectors must have same dimmensions.')
        else:
            subtracted = tuple(b - a for a, b in zip(self, V))
            return Vector(*subtracted)        

    def __mul__(self, V):
        '''The operator mult overloaded. You can multipy 2 vectors coordinate
         by coordinate.'''
        if type(V) == type(self):
            if len(self) != len(V):
                raise IndexError('Vectors must have same dimmensions')
            else:
                multiplied = tuple(a * b for a, b in zip(self, V))
        elif isinstance(V, type(1)) or isinstance(V, type(1.0)):
            multiplied = tuple(a * V for a in self)
        return Vector(*multiplied)

    __rmul__ = __mul__

    def __truediv__(self, V):
        if type(V) == type(self):
            if len(self) != len(V):
                raise IndexError('Vectors must have same dimmensions.')
            if 0 in V:
                raise ZeroDivisionError('Division by 0.')
            divided = tuple(a / b for a, b in zip(self, V))
        elif isinstance(V, int) or isinstance(V, float):
            divided = tuple(a / V for a in self)
        return Vector(*divided)

    __rtruediv__ = __truediv__

    def __pow__(self, n):
        '''The operator pow overloaded. You can powering vectors writing
         V ** n, where V is a vector, and n is the power. If V = (a, b), then
         V ** n calculates (a ** n, b ** n)'''
        powered = tuple(a ** n for a in self)
        return Vector(*powered)

    def __iadd__(self, t):
        sumplus = tuple(a + t for a in self)
        return Vector(*sumplus)

    def __isub__(self, t):
        subminus = tuple(a - t for a in self)
        return Vector(*subminus)

    def __imul__(self, t):
        mulplus = tuple(a * t for a in self)
        return Vector(*mulplus)

    def __itruediv__(self, t):
        divplus = tuple(a / t for a in self)
        return Vector(*divplus)

    def __ipow__(self, t):
        powplus = tuple(a ** t for a in self)
        return Vector(*powplus)

    def __neg__(self):
        '''The operator negative overloaded. If V is a vector, you can
        calculate -V, the vector V changed its sign in its coordinates.'''
        opposite = tuple(-1 * a for a in self)
        return Vector(*opposite)

    def tofloat(self):
        ''' It converts a vector to float vector.'''
        tofloatin = tuple(float(a) for a in self)
        return Vector(*tofloatin)

    def toint(self):
        ''' It converts a vector to integer vector.'''
        tointeger = tuple(int(a) for a in self)
        return Vector(*tointeger)

    def inner(self, V):
        ''' Returns the dot product (inner product or scalar product) of self
        and V vector
        '''
        return fsum(a * b for a, b in zip(self, V))

    def isorthog(self, V):
        '''Return if two vectors are or not orthogonals.'''
        return self.inner(V) == 0

    def norm(self):
        '''Returns the norm (length, magnitude) of the vector'''
        return sqrt(fsum(comp ** 2 for comp in self))

    def isunit(self):
        '''Returns if a vector has got norm equal 1 or not respect the
        euclidian norm.'''
        return self.norm() == 1

    def pnorm(self, p):
        '''Returns the p-norm of the vector'''
        return pow(fsum(abs(comp) ** p for comp in self), p)

    def infnorm(self):
        '''Returns the infinity norm of the vector'''
        return max(abs(comp) for comp in self)

    def normalize(self):
        '''Returns a normalized unit vector'''
        norm = self.norm()
        normed = tuple(comp / norm for comp in self)
        return Vector(*normed)

    def projection(self, V):
        ''' Returns the projection of 2 vectors.'''
        if len(self) != len(V):
            raise IndexError('Two vectors must have the same dimmension.')
        else:
            A = self.inner(V) / self.inner(self)
            return A * self

    def anglerad(self, V):
        ''' Returns the angle for 2 vectors in radians mode.'''
        angle = acos(self.inner(V) / (self.norm() * V.norm()))
        return angle

    def angledeg(self, V):
        ''' Returns the angle for 2 vectors in radians mode.'''
        angle = acos(self.inner(V) / (self.norm() * V.norm()))
        return degrees(angle)

    def prodvect(self, V):
        ''' Find out the vectorial product between two vectors'''
        if len(self) > 3 or len(V) > 3 or len(self) != len(V):
            raise IndexError('Sorry, two vectors must be 3D dimmensional.')
        else:
            e1 = Vector(1, 0, 0)
            e2 = Vector(0, 1, 0)
            e3 = Vector(0, 0, 1)
            det1 = self[1] * V[2] - self[2] * V[1]
            det2 = self[0] * V[2] - self[2] * V[0]
            det3 = self[0] * V[1] - self[1] * V[0]
            prodv = det1 * e1 - det2 * e2 + det3 * e3
            return prodv

    def areaparal(self, V):
        '''Find out the area of a paralelogram from 2 vectors'''
        return (self.prodvect(V)).norm()

    def normalprodvect(self, V):
        ''' Find out n = (a x b) / |a x b|, normal unit vector to the plane.'''
        return self.prodvect(V) / (self.prodvect(V)).norm()

    def prodmixt(self, V, W):
        ''' Find out the mixt product between three vectors'''
        if len(self) > 3 or len(V) > 3 or len(W) > 3 or len(self) != len(V)\
                or len(self) != len(W) or len(V) != len(W):
            raise IndexError('Sorry, three vectors must be 3D dimmensional.')
        else:
            det1 = V[1] * W[2] - V[2] * W[1]
            det2 = V[0] * W[2] - V[2] * W[0]
            det3 = V[0] * W[1] - V[1] * W[0]
            prodm = det1 * self[0] - det2 * self[1] + det3 * self[2]

            return prodm

    def volparal(self, V, W):
        '''Find out the paral.lepiped from three vectors'''
        return abs(self.prodmixt(V, W))

    def translate(self, t):
        ''' Find out the transalation vector t units.'''
        V = list(self)
        for i in range(0, len(V)):
            V[i] += t
        return Vector(*V)

    def rot2d(self, deg):
        ''' Find out the rotated vector a certain number of degrees in 2D.'''
        if len(self) != 2:
            raise IndexError('Sorry, vector must be 2D dimmensional.')
        else:
            rad = radians(deg)
            rot1 = Vector(cos(rad), -sin(rad))
            rot2 = Vector(sin(rad), cos(rad))
            p1 = rot1.inner(self)
            p2 = rot2.inner(self)
            rotated = Vector(p1, p2)
            return rotated

    def rot3d(self, N, deg):
        ''' Find out the rotated vector a certain number of degrees in 3D.'''
        if len(self) != 3:
            raise IndexError('Sorry, vector must be 3D dimmensional.')
        else:
            rad = radians(deg)

            c11 = (1 - N[0] ** 2) * cos(rad) + N[0] ** 2
            c12 = -N[0] * N[1] * cos(rad) - N[2] * sin(rad)
            c13 = -N[0] * N[2] * cos(rad) + N[1] * sin(rad)
            rot1 = Vector(c11, c12, c13)

            c21 = -N[0] * N[1] * cos(rad) + N[2] * sin(rad)
            c22 = (1 - N[1] ** 2) * cos(rad) + N[1] ** 2
            c23 = -N[1] * N[2] * cos(rad) - N[0] * sin(rad)
            rot2 = Vector(c21, c22, c23)

            c31 = -N[0] * N[2] * cos(rad) - N[1] * sin(rad)
            c32 = -N[1] * N[2] * cos(rad) + N[0] * sin(rad)
            c33 = (1 - N[2] ** 2) * cos(rad) + N[2] ** 2
            rot3 = Vector(c31, c32, c33)

            p1 = rot1.inner(self)
            p2 = rot2.inner(self)
            p3 = rot3.inner(self)
            rotated = Vector(p1, p2, p3)
            return rotated

    def rect2pol(self):
        ''' Converts rectangular coordinates in a 2D vector to polar
        oordinates in radians way.'''
        if len(self) != 2:
            raise ValueError("The vector must be a 2D.")
        else:
            self0 = hypot(self[0], self[1])
            if self[0] == 0.:
                raise ZeroDivision("Error division, the denominator is zero.")
            else:
                self1 = atan2(self[1], self[0])
        return Vector(self0, self1)

    def rect2poldeg(self):
        ''' Converts rectangular coordinates in a 2D vector to polar
        coordinates in sexagesimal degrees way.'''
        V = self.rect2pol()
        V0 = V[0]
        V1 = degrees(V[1])
        return Vector(V0, V1)

    def pol2rect(self):
        ''' Converts polar coordinates in a 2D vector to rectangular
        coordinates in radians way.'''
        if len(self) != 2:
            raise ValueError("The vector must be a 2D.")
        else:
            if self[0] < 0.:
                raise ValueError("The radius must be positive.")
            else:
                self0 = self[0] * cos(self[1])
            self1 = self[0] * sin(self[1])
        return Vector(self0, self1)

    def pol2rectdeg(self):
        ''' Converts rectangular coordinates in a 2D vector to polar
        coordinates in sexagesimal degrees way.'''
        if len(self) != 2:
            raise ValueError("The vector must be a 2D.")
        else:
            if self[0] < 0.:
                raise ValueError("The radius must be positive.")
            else:
                self0 = self[0] * cos(radians(self[1]))
            self1 = self[0] * sin(radians(self[1]))
        return Vector(self0, self1)

    def rect2cyl(self):
        ''' Converts rectangular coordinates in a 3D vector to cylindrical
        coordinates in radians way.'''
        if len(self) != 3:
            raise ValueError("The vector must be a 3D.")
        else:
            V = Vector(self[0], self[1])
            W = V.rect2pol()
        return Vector(W[0], W[1], self[2])

    def rect2cyldeg(self):
        ''' Converts rectangular coordinates in a 3D vector to cylindrical
        coordinates in sexagesimal degrees way.'''
        if len(self) != 3:
            raise ValueError("The vector must be a 3D.")
        else:
            V = Vector(self[0], self[1])
            W = V.rect2poldeg()
        return Vector(W[0], W[1], self[2])

    def cyl2rect(self):
        ''' Converts cylindrical coordinates in a 3D vector to rectangular
        coordinates in radians way.'''
        if len(self) != 3:
            raise ValueError("The vector must be a 3D.")
        else:
            V = Vector(self[0], self[1])
            W = V.pol2rect()
        return Vector(W[0], W[1], self[2])

    def cyl2rectdeg(self):
        ''' Converts cylindrical coordinates in a 3D vector to rectangular
        coordinates in sexagesimal degrees way.'''
        if len(self) != 3:
            raise ValueError("The vector must be a 3D.")
        else:
            V = Vector(self[0], self[1])
            W = V.pol2rectdeg()
        return Vector(W[0], W[1], self[2])

    def rect2sph(self):
        ''' Converts rectangular coordinates in a 3D vector to spherical
        coordinates in radians way.'''
        if len(self) != 3:
            raise ValueError("The vector must be a 3D.")
        else:
            self0 = sqrt(pow(self[0], 2.) +
                         pow(self[1], 2.) + pow(self[2], 2.))
            self1 = atan2(sqrt(pow(self[0], 2.) + pow(self[1], 2.)), self[2])
            self2 = atan2(self[1], self[0])
            return Vector(self0, self1, self2)

    def rect2sphdeg(self):
        ''' Converts rectangular coordinates in a 3D vector to spherical
         coordinates in sexagesimal degrees way.'''
        if len(self) != 3:
            raise ValueError("The vector must be a 3D.")
        else:
            V = self.rect2sph()
            return Vector(V[0], degrees(V[1]), degrees(V[2]))

    def sph2rect(self):
        ''' Converts spherical coordinates in a 3D vector to rectangular
         coordinates in radians way.'''
        if len(self) != 3:
            raise IndexError('The vector must be 3D.')
        if self[0] < 0:
            raise ValueError('The radius must be positive.')
        else:
            self0 = self[0] * sin(self[1]) * cos(self[2])
            self1 = self[0] * sin(self[1]) * sin(self[2])
            self2 = self[0] * cos(self[1])
            return Vector(self0, self1, self2)

    def sph2rectdeg(self):
        ''' Converts spherical coordinates in a 3D vector to rectangular
         coordinates in sexagesimal degrees way.'''
        if len(self) != 3:
            raise IndexError('The vector must be 3D.')
        if self[0] < 0:
            raise ValueError('The radius must be positive.')
        else:
            self0 = self[0] * sin(radians(self[1])) * cos(radians(self[2]))
            self1 = self[0] * sin(radians(self[1])) * sin(radians(self[2]))
            self2 = self[0] * cos(radians(self[1]))
            return Vector(self0, self1, self2)

    def cyl2sph(self):
        ''' Converts cylindrical coordinates in a 3D vector to spherical
         coordinates.'''
        if len(self) != 3:
            raise IndexError('The vector must be 3D.')
        if self[0] < 0:
            raise ValueError('The radius must be positive.')
        else:
            self0 = sqrt(pow(self[0], 2.) + pow(self[2], 2.))
            self1 = atan2(self[0], self[2])
            self2 = self[1]
            return Vector(self0, self1, self2)

    def sph2cyl(self):
        ''' Converts spherical coordinates in a 3D vector to cylindrical
         coordinates.'''
        if len(self) != 3:
            raise IndexError('The vector must be 3D.')
        if self[0] < 0:
            raise ValueError('The radius must be positive.')
        else:
            self0 = self[0] * sin(self[1])
            self1 = self[2]
            self2 = self[0] * cos(self[1])
            return Vector(self0, self1, self2)

    def sph2cyldeg(self):
        ''' Converts spherical coordinates in a 3D vector to cylindrical
         coordinates in sexagesimal degrees way.'''
        if len(self) != 3:
            raise IndexError('The vector must be 3D.')
        if self[0] < 0:
            raise ValueError('The radius must be positive.')
        else:
            self0 = self[0] * sin(radians(self[1]))
            self1 = self[2]
            self2 = self[0] * cos(radians(self[1]))
            return Vector(self0, self1, self2)
```

All the code is here in [git](https://github.com/tofol/Python-Programs). You are welcome to contribute patches to the repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclassing `tuple` makes Python treat your `Vector` objects as immutable. As such they should not have any mutable state and hence no `__init__` method. Do all initialization in `__new__` instead:

```
def __new__(cls, *V):
    if not V:
        V = (0, 0)
    elif len(V) == 1:
        raise ValueError('A vector must have at least 2 coordinates.')
    return tuple.__new__(cls, V)
```

The only methods that refer to `self.V` are `__len__`, `__getitem__`, `__iter__` and `__repr__`, none of which add any functionality over what `tuple` provides. You could remove all four methods and rely on the inherited ones instead.

Comment: Fixed in my git repo. Now I understand the differences between new, init and repr. Do you know how to overload tofloat and toint methods. I tried it but it didn't work to me. I tried with __float__ and __int__

Comment: @Tobal overloading ``__float__`` and ``__int__`` for that isn’t the correct way -- these are supposed to return actual floats and integers. Returning a vector of floats/integers is unexpected and will lead to unexpected behaviour in user code. Implementing ``norm()`` as ``__abs__`` is an option though.

Answer (score 3):

- ```
  def __sub__(self, V):
      '''The operator subtraction overloaded. You can subtract points writing
      V - W, where V and W are two vectors.'''
      if len(self) != len(V):
          raise IndexError('Vectors must have same dimmensions.')
      else:
          subtracted = tuple(a - b for a, b in zip(self, V))
          return Vector(*subtracted)

  __rsub__ = __sub__
  ```

  This implementation of `__rsub__` will create wrong results:

  ```
  >>> import Vector
  >>> v = Vector.Vector(1, 1)
  >>> (0, 0) - v
  (1, 1)
  ```

  `__rsub__` is called when no working `__sub__` implementation is found for the left hand side of an operator. The arguments are then in reverse order with respect to the way `__sub__` is called.
- In general, when your operator implementation cannot deal with the type of the operand, `return NotImplemented` (not `NotImplementedError`). Python will then allow the `__r*__` operator of the operand to be executed, allowing for more extensibility. For example, if you make a Matrix implementation at some point in the future, it might implement multiplication of vectors from the left by implementing `__rmul__`, if your `__mul__` implementation returns `NotImplemented` when encountering an unknown type.
- Your support of operands is in general not consistent, but I’m not sure whether that is relevant to your actual question – you might be aware of this. However, addition and subtraction can work with tuples as operands, while true division can only work with scalars.
- Using `type(1)` seems not good to me. If using `isinstance` at all, you should use the types such as [numbers.Number](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#numbers.Number).
- Your implementation of the `__i*__` operators looks as if you accidentially took them for integer operators. Instead, they are supposed to be the implementations of `+=` et al., working with the same operands as `+`, for example. Please refer to [the python documentation on Special Method Names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) for details of the semantics expected.
- I have not gone through any method below `norm`, because I know much of this not certain enough off the top of my head, I however have some more general remarks.
- Refactor your exceptions out, to allow for reuse and consistent error messages. Example:

  ```
      @staticmethod
      def _dimension_mismatch(d1, d2):
          raise IndexError(
              "Vectors must have same dimensionality (got {} and {})".format(
                  d1, d2))
  ```

  (alternatively, use a global function instead of `@staticmethod`)
- There is no point in having constructs such as:

  ```
  if a:
      raise Something()
  else:
      do_something()
  ```

  Throwing an exception will disrupt the control flow, so it doesn’t matter whether you have an else branch or just continue your code like this:

  ```
  if a:
      raise Something()
  do_something()
  ```

  The latter improves readability by requiring less indentation depth.

Comment: ok, i've fixed the subtraction, i've got only one  problem with div when i want 0/V = 0 it gives an incorrect output. I've upload the fixes to github, now. About the doc I'll fix it. About the product is correct. Multiply matrices is be able using inner (dot) product. Some parts of your text i don't understand very well, i'm not speaking english, sorry. Thanks